# Application crashes when web service is down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

how to handle when web service is down.

I loged in application and its Re-Directed to result screen.

When i turn off the web services my application is crashing.

How to handle this kind of issue

Comment: You can use reachablility code provided by apple.

Comment: What are the objects in your application? Are you using any connections to server?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to that file.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html

to check for internet connectivity.

Comment: This is Reachability switching to another network....  but i do have wifi while working its status is on. When i am log into client web service and turn off the client web service my application is crashed.

Comment: what are the log statements that you are getting

Comment: When Web Service is done its sending nil or empty string has response.  loading request in array. talking response from object at index.  if nil its crash.

Comment: Then check if the object coming back is nil and handle the problems accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using NSURLConnection then handle it in

```
     - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)err {
}
```